# adding validation to answer in quiz gives wrong answers

Tags: python

I am a complete novice with Python and working on a multiple choice quiz that reads questions from a file and keeps a score that then writes to a file.

Everything was working perfectly until I added validation to the answers given by the user.  Now when I run the program it says my answers are incorrect!

What have I done?

Version 1 that works

```
def inputandoutput():
    questions_file = open_file("questions.txt", "r")
    title = next_line(questions_file)
    welcome(title)
    score = 0

    # get first block
    category, question, answers, correct, explanation = next_block(questions_file)
    while category:
        # ask a question
        print(category)
        print(question)
        for i in range(4):
            print("\t", i + 1, "-", answers[i])

        # get answer
        answer = input("What's your answer?: ")

        # check answer
        if answer == correct:
            print("\nRight!", end=" ")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("\nWrong.", end=" ")
        print(explanation)
        print("Score:", score, "\n\n")

        # get next block
        category, question, answers, correct, explanation = next_block(questions_file)


    questions_file.close()
```

version 2 that says I now have the wrong answers

```
def inputandoutput():
    questions_file = open_file("questions.txt", "r")
    title = next_line(questions_file)
    welcome(title)
    score = 0

    # get first block
    category, question, answers, correct, explanation = next_block(questions_file)
    while category:
        # ask a question
        print(category)
        print(question)
        for i in range(4):
            print("\t", i + 1, "-", answers[i])


        # get answer and validate
        while True:
            try:
                answer = int(input("What's your answer?: "))
                if answer in range (1,5):
                    break
            except ValueError:
                print ("That's not a number")
            else:
                print ("the number needs to be between 1 and 4, try again ")


        # check answer
        if answer == correct:
            print("\nRight!", end=" ")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("\nWrong.", end=" ")
        print(explanation)
        print("Score:", score, "\n\n")

        # get next block
        category, question, answers, correct, explanation = next_block(questions_file)
```

Help?

Answer (score 4):

In your original version, `answer` was a string; in your new version, it is an `int`.

If you change your `try` body to be:

```
answer = input("What's your answer?: ")
if int(answer) in range (1,5):
```

then you can still catch the `ValueError` but leave `answer` a string.

Comment: ok yes I see that now.  If the read file has answer headings as strings then - how do I validate the user entry so it matches?